# How to change angular-moment locale?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, angular-moment, minifiedjs

I'm trying to use French version of moment, but `moment.locale('fr')` doesn't work and it doesn't change the language:

```
console.debug(moment.locale()); 
moment.locale('fr'); 
console.debug(moment.locale());
console.debug(moment.locales());
```

**output**:

```
en
en
TypeError: moment.locales is not a function
```

gulpfile.js:

```
var path={
    js:
    [
        {
            src:
                [
                    'bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js',
                    'bower_components/moment/locale/fr.js',
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the french definition

```
import 'moment/locale/fr'
moment.locale('fr')
```

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/loading-into-browser/

Comment: Thanks for your response; however it didn't solve my problem.
I already have imported them (moment.min.js and fr.js), I also tried moment-with-locales.js but none works.